# Distribution-free learning vs distribution-dependent learning

Tags: machine-learning, learning-theory

I came across some papers studying the problem of distribution-free learning, and I am interested in knowing the exact definition of distribution-free learning.

I have searched some literature:

In [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.03714.pdf), ''distribution-free setting, in which no explicit assumptions are made on the underlying distribution, but only on the learned hypothesis.''

In the book [Learning and Generalization](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4471-3748-1), Chapter 6 is on Learning under a fixed probability, and Chapter 7 is on Distribution-free learning. It says ''the probability measure generating the sample can be any probability measure on the underlying measurable space. In other words, there is a complete absence of any prior
knowledge about the underlying probability measure.''

I also know some papers that made some assumptions about (but not exactly fixing) the underlying distribution, which, in my opinion, lies in between the above two scenarios, e.g., [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1211.1082.pdf).

So my current understanding of distribution-free learning is that if $D_X$ (the underlying distribution), or some property of $D_X$, e.g., log-concave distribution, is known to the learner, then it is a distribution-dependent learning scenario. As a sequence, the label complexity in this setting may depend on the parameters of $D_X$.

On the other hand, if the structure of $D_X$ is completely agnostic to the learner, then it is distribution-free learning. Although the learner does not know anything about $D_X$, the goal is to output a hypothesis that achieves an excess error guarantee.

I would like to know whether my interpretation of these concepts is correct. Thanks a lot for any thoughts and comments!

Comment: Yes, all correct. Btw, might be better to ask this on cstheory stack exchange.